# How to crop image on the detected houghlines?

Tags: python, crop, scikit-image, houghlines

I am developing a book spine detection solution. For that I am trying to crop the image using the hough lines detected. However I am stuck at this phase. Here's the code which I am using to detect the book spines:

```
image = skimage.io.imread(fname='img.jpeg', as_gray=True)

edges = skimage.feature.canny(image=image,sigma=1.2,)

tested_angles = np.linspace(-np.pi/18, np.pi/18, 20)
h, theta, d = hough_line(edges, tested_angles)

for _, angle, dist in zip(*hough_line_peaks(h, theta, d)):
    y0 = (dist - 0 * np.cos(angle)) / np.sin(angle)
    y1 = (dist - image.shape[1] * np.cos(angle)) / np.sin(angle)
    ax.plot((0, image.shape[1]), (y0, y1), '-r')
```

[Here's is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsJKM.png)

I am happy with the hough transformation, however I am not able to figure out how to use this output to crop the image in between the houghlines detected. The confusing bit is how can I convert the `y0`, `y1` into `x,y` coordinates that I can use to crop the image. I am very new to image processing, any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: To clarify, you want to create N sub-images, each with a book inside?